# Xcode 11 can't be installed on macOS Mojave 10.14.6

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

This is my first ever post. I am new to programming with zero experience and have signed up for iOS app development course with one of the online education services.

Coming to the question, I have Mojave 10.14.6 on my mac(pro 13 inch 2015) and I'm trying to install Xcode 11 from the App store. The error/popup that I get when clicking on install is below.

"
We Could  not complete your purchase.

Xcode can't be installed on "Flash" because macOS version 10.15.2. or later is required.

"

I can't update my macOS to latest(Cataline) version since it is not yet compatible with my company's remote working requirements.

Is there a way that I could install Xcode without updating the OS ?

Comment: hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. you can download older version of XCode from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=xcode .

Answer (score 10):

xcode 11.4.x requires macOS 10.15.2 or later
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_4_release_notes

you can install xcode 11.3.x if you have macOS 10.14.6
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_3_release_notes

Comment: Thanks Marv. I went through the link and it seems it is only available via Apple developer account which I don't have as of now.

Comment: Xcode 11.4 includes SDKs for iOS 13.4, iPadOS 13.4, tvOS 13.4, watchOS 6.2, and macOS Catalina 10.15.4. The Xcode 11.4 release supports on-device debugging for iOS 8 and later, tvOS 9 and later, and watchOS 2 and later. Xcode 11.4 requires a Mac running macOS Catalina 10.15.2 or later.

Comment: Xcode 11.3 supports developing apps for iOS 13.3, iPadOS 13.3, tvOS 13.3, watchOS 6.1, and macOS Catalina 10.15.2. Xcode 11.3 supports on-device debugging for iOS 8 and later, tvOS 9 and later, and watchOS 2 and later. Xcode 11.3 requires a Mac running macOS Mojave 10.14.4 or later.

Comment: is it worth signing up for Apple dev account($99/year) ? considering I'm just starting to learn coding. or is there another way to get Xcode 11.3 ?

Comment: See @HardBoiledPotato's answer. It helped me.

Comment: Just as a quick side-rant, what a horrible UX experience by Apple, still, after so many years. I cannot believe there's no simple filter to choose your macOS version

Comment: @RMR You can get it with a free account - it doesn't have to be the paid one. Just go to https://developer.apple.com/download/more/. (Oops - I just copied the essence of RMR's answer by mistake - please vote that up)

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried checking https://developer.apple.com/download/more/? I used it without having a paid developer account (the $99/year) – only signed in with my non-developer Apple ID (just needed to agree to the TOC).

By using this account you will be redirected to the https://developer.apple.com/download/ URL when clicking the downloads button; just add "more" behind it and you can access the file.
I don't think it is worth it paying USD$99 when you are still learning; a lot of people learn ios development without paying the developer account.
Just purchase it when you want to release your first app to the App Store.

I wanted to add a comment to the accepted answer but didn't have the reputation required.